# ruby float arithmetic array

Tags: ruby

I'm doing math on array members (Floats). The types looks correct. Still I get strange error. There is no `nil` value at all. What is this error?

```
nil can't be coerced into Float
```

Step 1

```
newFront = [412.5, 312.5]
@direction = [1.0, 0.0]
@length = 50.0
retRear = [newFront[0] - (@direction[0] * @lenght), newFront[1] - (@direction[1] * @lenght)]
# => TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Float
#   from (irb):13:in `*'
#   from (irb):13
#   from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Step 2

```
newFront[0].class # => Float
@direction[0].class # => Float
@length.class # => Float
```

Step 3

```
nfx = Float(newFront[0]) # => 412.5
dx = Float(@direction[0]) # => 1.0
nfy = Float(newFront[1]) # => 312.5
dy = Float(@direction[1]) # => 0.0
@l = 50.0
retRear = [nfx - (dx * @l), nfy - (dy * @l)] # => [362.5, 312.5]
```

That is what I want. Does Ruby want to tell me that I can't use Arrays for Float arithmetic at all? Also, rewriting the same as one expression fails too.

```
retRear = [Float(newFront[0]) - (Float(@direction[0]) * Float(@lenght)), Float(newFront[1]) - (Float(@direction[1]) * Float(@lenght))]
# => TypeError: can't convert nil into Float
#   from (irb):78:in `Float'
#   from (irb):78
#   from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You have a typo - `@lenght` instead of `@length`.  That's probably where your nil is coming from.

Comment: @WallyAltman: Make it an answer! This is definitely it.

Comment: ah wally didnt see you! my bad

Comment: There's at least *one* `nil` I bet.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo - `@lenght` instead of `@length`.

Answer (score 1):

As @WallyAltman pointed out, You misspelled `@length`, hence the nil.

I would do it this way, btw:

```
new_front = [412.5, 312.5]
@direction = [1.0, 0.0]
@length = 50.0
ret_rear = new_front.zip(@direction).map do |front, dir|
  front - dir * @length
end
# => [362.5, 312.5]
```

Comment: can you join here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27184/ruby-conceptual

Answer (score 1):

The nil is coming from your typo.  @length is set to 50, but there is no value set for the variable @lenght (note the transposed "h" and "t").